# PHP date wrong textual day, but date correct

Tags: php, date

This is weird, i'm trying to echo out a date like Monday, January 1, 2013, but its echoing out the wrong textual day. I don't have a clue why?

I have:

```
<?php echo date('l, F n, Y', strtotime($do['dueDate'])); ?>
```

And $do['dueDate'] is the date from the database of "2013-03-22". Its formatted as DATE in mysql.

When the above echos out it says: Friday, March 3, 2013

But march 3, 2013 is a sunday...

Comment: Check the [date manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) see what `n` means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
echo date('l ,F j ,Y', strtotime($do['dueDate']));
```

Comment: I'm a freaking moron. Sorry. I looked at the PHP.net docs wrong. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
n --> Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros --> 1 through 12
j --> Day of the month without leading zeros                   --> 1 to 31


<?php
 $do['dueDate'] =  "2013-03-22";
 echo date('l, F j, Y', strtotime($do['dueDate']));
?>
```

Output :

```
Friday, March 22, 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<?php  
echo date('l, F j, Y', strtotime("2013-03-22"));  // output Friday, March 22, 2013
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/rF6w1U

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

n is the numerical representation of the month.

try this:

```
$date = "2013-03-22";
echo date('l, F j, Y', strtotime($date));
```

outputs:

```
Friday, March 22, 2013
```